# Addition on a normed space is continuous

Tags: general-topology

I have seen some answers regarding this question but I am still confused about how to solve it using $\delta-\epsilon$.

***Probably wrong attempt:***

$+: V$x$V \to V$ be the function I want to prove it is continuous.

I think I have to define a norm on $V$x$V$ which can be $||(a,b)|| = ||a|| + ||b||$

So, I guess that for every $\epsilon > 0$, I have to find a $\delta >0$ such that if $||(a,b) - (c,d)|| < \delta$, then $||$+$(a,b) -                 $+$(c,d)|| < \epsilon$

I think that $||(a,b) - (c,d)|| = ||(a-c, b-d)|| = ||a-c|| + ||b-d||$

$||$+$(a,b) -                 $+$(c,d)||$ = $||(a+b) - (c+d)||$ now I use triangle inequality so $\leq ||a-c|| + ||b-d||$ $< \delta < \epsilon$

Thanks as usual!

Comment: The norm you defined in the product can be seen as ''rectangles''. The definition of a continuous function is that the preimage of an open set is open. It is true that for every point $x$ on every open set of $V$ there is a ball of radius $r$ and center $x$ inside the open set. However you need to prove that the same holds for your  ''rectangles ' in $V \times V$. Hint: it is enough to prove that for the open sets of the form $A \times B$.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that you think that you have to define a norm on $V\times V$ and that you decided to define it as$$\|(a,b)\|=\|a\|+\|b\|\tag1$$Actually, you can define it in several ways. You can take, for instance $\|(a,b)\|=\sqrt{\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2}$ or $\|(a,b)\|=\max\{\|a\|,\|b\|\}$. It doesn't matter these norms are equivalent. I will use the norm $(1)$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Now, if $\|(a,b)-(c,d)\|<\varepsilon$, then $\|(a-c,b-d)\|<\varepsilon$; in other words, $\|a-c\|+\|b-d\|<\varepsilon$. But then$$\|+(a,b)-+(c,d)\|=\|a+b-c-d\|\leqslant\|a-c\|+\|b-d\|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: So what I wrote was "okay"? Thanks for your explanation about norms.

Comment: Yes, it is OK. Note that, in the case of the norm that I have used, $\delta=\varepsilon$. But you may have to use a different $\delta$ for other norms.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much.